# CSS: Sizing of elements in cells of a table with partial borders

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

##### What I Want

With **pure HTML and CSS**, to have a table where each cell either:

- has a border
- contains an element that is the same size as the full cell

such that there are no visible gaps between cells.

Visually, I have the left but need the right

[image]  [image]

##### What I've Tried

I've tried playing around with setting various combinations of `box-sizing` and `padding` to no avail.

You can see one of my attempts at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn6u1Lv5/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You have added `padding:0` to just the coloured cells. As the first cell still have padding, it is increasing all the row height.

If you add:

```
.rows-index {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You will notice there's still a white 1px line which is not white, It is the space the border of the first cell is taking (as before, increasing the row hight). It does not matter if use `border-box` in this table. All cells will have same height but the coloured `divs` won't fill that gap.

I would suggest to use `outline` insteed of border as a solution:

```css
table  {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.cols-index, .rows-index {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-cell {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-cell div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


.purple    { background-color: purple; }
.red       { background-color: red; }
.lightblue { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="top-left-cell"></th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bish</th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bash</th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bosh</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rows-index">First</td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="purple">A</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="purple">B</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="purple">C</div></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rows-index">Second</td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="red">D</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="red">E</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="red">F</div></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rows-index">Third</td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="lightblue">G</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="lightblue">H</div></td>
        <td class="table-cell"><div class="lightblue">I</div></td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edited:** your `height:100%;` in the coloured divs is not doing anything as the parent does not have a fixed height. If you don't want to use `outline` you could set the height of this `divs`  to 19px which is the height of the first cell... the cell that set the height of your rows. However this "solution" is ugly as hell and won't work if anytime any cell has 2 lines of text.

**Edited... again**: or third option, using `border` would be to set a `line-height` to your coloured `divs`. This is much cleaner than the previous edited paragraph and it will work as a kind of `padding`: https://jsfiddle.net/654gu2sf/

Answer (score 0):

You can 'extend' the cells' coloring a little with padding and border to fill up the blank spaces (which can be seen to correspond to the borders in the first column).

An adjusment has to be made in the first row in the table body which is not given a top 'extension'.

```css
table * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.cols-index,
.rows-index {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-cell {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-cell div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.table-cell div {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: var(--col);
  border-top: var(--col) 1px solid;
  border-bottom: var(--col) 1px solid;
}

.purple {
  --col: purple;
}

.red {
  --col: red
}

.lightblue {
  --col: lightblue;
}

tbody tr:first-child td>div {
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.rows-index {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="top-left-cell"></th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bish</th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bash</th>
      <th class="cols-index">Bosh</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rows-index">First</td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="purple">A</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="purple">B</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="purple">C</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rows-index">Second</td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="red">D</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="red">E</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="red">F</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rows-index">Third</td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="lightblue">G</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="lightblue">H</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell">
        <div class="lightblue">I</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the cellspacing attribute to to table tag to adjust spacing between cells.

To remove the spacing, set cellspacing=0.

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>bish</th>
    <th>bash</th>
    <th>bosh</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cellspacing does still work on lots of browsers but it is deprecated so probably not a good idea to use it see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/cellSpacing

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly.